# Foreign key pointing to a primary key which is also part of an unique key

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, dbeaver

I created a database using MariaDb. I have the following `author` table (with `id` as primary key), which is extended by two other tables,  `author_personal` and `author_corporate`, representing two different kinds of author and having different fields:

```
CREATE TABLE `author` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author_type` char(1) NOT NULL,
  -- other fields
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `author_UN` (`id`,`author_type`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `author_CHECK_type` CHECK (`author_type` in ('P','C'))
);

CREATE TABLE `author_personal` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  -- other fields
  `author_type` char(1) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ('P') VIRTUAL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `author_personal_FK` (`id`,`author_type`),
  CONSTRAINT `author_personal_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`id`, `author_type`) REFERENCES `author` (`id`, `author_type`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE `author_corporate` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `corporate_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `corporate_acronym` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `author_type` char(1) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ('C') VIRTUAL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `author_corporate_FK` (`id`,`author_type`),
  CONSTRAINT `author_corporate_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`id`, `author_type`) REFERENCES `author` (`id`, `author_type`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Although `author.id` would be enough, I decided to create an UNIQUE KEY (`id`, `author_type`) to be referenced by the foreign key in the two other tables, so that it would be impossible to reference from `author_personal` an `author` which is not flagged as P, and from `author_corporate` an `author` which is not flagged as C.

The problem rises when I want to reference `author` using the primary key, like in this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `work_authors` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `work_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `author_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  -- other fields
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `work_authors_FK` (`work_id`),
  KEY `work_authors_FK_author` (`author_id`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `work_authors_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`work_id`) REFERENCES `work` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `work_authors_FK_author` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `author` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Both DBeaver and PhpMyAdmin think that `work_authors_FK_author` references `author_UN` instead of the actual primary key (`author.id`).

[image: DBeaver Foreign Key description]

This means that I am not able to click on the values in `work_authors.author_id` and open the referenced record in `authors` because I get the following error:

`Entity [davide_library.author] association [work_authors_FK_author] columns differs from referenced constraint [author_UN] (1<>2)`

I created the foreign keys using DBeaver. Although I selected `PRIMARY` as the unique key, in the list of foreign keys it always show `author_UN` as the referenced object. I don't know if this behavior depends on MariaDB or DBeaver.

**My question is:**

Is there any way to explicitily reference in the DDL the primary key instead of the unique key?

**or, alternatively:**

Is there a different way, other than the UNUQUE constraint, to check that `author_personal` references only authors flagged with P, and the same for `author_corporate`?

Comment: Hi - given that author.id is unique by definition, as it is the PK, why have you created a unique index on id, author_type? It is redundant and adds no value, as far as I can see.

Comment: Hi! I have two kinds of author, discriminated by `author_type` (which can assume the values P and C). Depending on the type, there are additional informations about the author in two other tables, `author_personal` (P) and `author_corporate` (C). These two tables also have the `author_type` column. The purpose of the UNIQUE key is to ensure that a record in `author` flagged with P do NOT correspond to a record in `author_personal`.

Comment: If you are enforcing `author_type` in your `author` table wouldn't it be enough to just have the `author_id` in the additional information table (do you need to separate personal and corporate if `author_id` is unique)?

Comment: Yes, but "id" is unique - therefore it is not possible to have 2 records with the same id but different author_type values

Comment: @Dave  @NickW you are both right, `author_id` is sufficient, but I have done that for a different reason. I want to avoid the following situations: 1) if `author_type` is P, it should not be allowed to create a corresponding record in `author_personal`, and 2) if a record is present in `author_personal` the corresponding `author_type` must not be changed from P to C. This UNIQUE key is useless for the reference but is needed to avoid those errors.

Comment: Why do you have separate tables for `personal` and `corporate`? Use the `author_id` as the key in a single table with the additional details. If there may be both personal and corporate (which sounds like is NOT the case) using a P or C flag in that table.

Comment: @Dave I have separate tables because there are different fields depending on the type: a "personal author" has name and surname, a "corporate author" has a website and other fields

Comment: @Dave I found that other people use UNIQUE in the same way as I do: see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37443/how-to-represent-class-table-inheritance-current-dbms-specific-way-please) and [here](https://www.sqlteam.com/articles/implementing-table-inheritance-in-sql-server)